# Python: no module named unittest. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, unit-testing

It seems strange that a module from the std Python lib to be missing. I'm probably doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what exactly.

```
shift@bt:~/experiments/$ python test/test_creation.py 
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test_creation.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
ImportError: No module named unittest
```

Running with the -v switch shows this:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test_creation.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
ImportError: No module named unittest
# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 3 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats
```

Where should I look to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: 1. Does your script fiddle around with `sys.path`?  2. What's the output of `env | grep PYTHON`? 3. Does `import unittest` work in the interactive interpreter?

Comment: 1. No. 2. PYTHONHOME=/home/shift/experiments/lib 3. No.

Comment: perhaps a stupid question, but you don't have some bogus character in your .py file after "unittest"? Does it work from idle or when just starting pyton and typing "import unittest"?

Comment: check where your PYTHONHOME is set to, ops didnt see the comment. well, now you know where to look. that env is messing things up :)

Comment: @Fredrik, it doesn't work from the interactive interpreter either. @ashwoods, my PYTHONHOME is set to /home/shift/experiments/lib, the same folder as the test folder is in, though I didn't set it manually.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-441200.html grep your files and see what script, settings, or whatever is setting that env variable. try calling the script with the -E (ignore env variables) http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html

Comment: just to make sure, you have your python environment installed into /home/shift/experiments/lib ? see  http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME

Comment: Could you paste the value of sys.path? Try looking where unittest.py is on your system and post the result here.

Comment: 1. How did you install Python?  2. What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Hm, it seems to think I installed Python in /home/shift/experiments/lib, as all the paths in sys.path have that. I opened a new terminal, and the problem is no longer there. Probably I messed it up somehow. Guys, post something as answers, so I can vote them up.

Comment: @Sven Marnach, it was already installed. I have Backtrack Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your python environment installed into `/home/shift/experiments/lib` ? see docs.python.org on [PYTHONHOME](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME)

Comment: No, it somehow got set to that value, and from there on, all hell broke loose.